# get_posts() returns empty on custom post type /wp-admin/edit.php

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, get-posts

I need to do a get_posts() to fetch a list of "product" type posts, but when I do it on edit.php?post_type=mycustompost it returns empty. If I just simply do the same function but on edit.php (posts index page) it returns properly.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_admin_head');

function custom_admin_head() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 30,
    );
    $products = get_posts($args);
```

In this example

on edit.php?post_type=mycustompost... $products is empty

on edit.php... $products has 30 entries

How do I get it to return all 30 entries on the custom post type edit.php in wp-admin?

Comment: Are parent/child posts involved?

Comment: I'm trying to load it on an edit.php from a custom post type that I have setup in functions.php. I'm not sure if a parent/child post would be involved in that, but the custom post type is not hierarchical if that helps.